# log4j: How to log logger name?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to put Logger name into every log. Now I use

`logger.error(logger.getName());`.

Is there any better way? I don't want to use `%m` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [%c option](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns) in your logging text.